# Push changes to remote repo without commit

Tags: git

Is it possible to push changes to a remote repository without commiting to the master branch? I use the remote repo just for deploying.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "I use the remote repo just for deploying."? Do you want to use Git as a replacement for an SSH client just pushing changes?

Comment: I think he meant deploying apps that use a git repo as source, like e.g. Heroku does

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that, as it would completely oppose the whole "git strategy", I guess. I don't know about your deployment system, but I guess a good way to do what you are trying to is to work on different branches (that is, on for development and one which gets deployed when pushed to), and merging the changes you want to be deployed from your development-branch into your live branch.

Comment: While correct from a git workflow perspective, this does not answer the question. Sometimes it **is** necessary to push without actual changes to retrigger failed backend processes.

Answer (score 106):

You can create an empty commit and push that: `git commit --allow-empty`

Comment: This is what I was looking for, though fresskoma is technically right it was not helpful to the actual question.

Answer (score 9):

You can amend your last commit with the `--no-edit` option then force push the branch.

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
git push origin <remote name> -f
```

Answer (score 6):

No, you must make a commit before you can push. What is being pushed is the commit (or commits).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to push a specific commit:

```
git push <remotename> <commit SHA>:<remotebranchname>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I use is to use `git diff` to get a patch file and then apply the patch to remote repo with `patch`.

I have no automatic tested script to propose, but the idea is to reset remote repo to the same state as local repo using `git reset --hard`

Then `git diff > patch.txt`, transfer patch file, and apply with `patch -p0 < patch.txt`.

This should work for simple modifications, but won't work with deleted/added files and other changes.

Answer (score 0):

I get that when we push changes directly without generating a commit so changes don't reflect in the corresponding branch, you must generate a commit either it will empty or not before pushing into the origin.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).