# Git, push working directory without committing

Tags: git

Sometimes I'll be working on code on a desktop then find I have to go*, before I've finished implementing a full feature. Then later ill be on another computer, and want to carry on where I left off. Is it possible to push the working directory (so without committing) to a remote repo (such as on GitHub)?

* I ran this will happen suddenly, so I need to go quickly and not have to think about writing a commit message.

Comment: I don't understand - you committed, but didn't push, from your desktop directory before you left, is that correct?  Now, you want to go to another computer and get the changes that you didn't push?  Or *did* you push them?

Comment: Are you asking if uncommitted changes can be pushed?

Comment: If you don't have to commit and push to a temp branch (which doesnt't take much time, btw…), then create a script for it.

Comment: @BobGilmore, I have no idea why the title said "without changes" I meant "without committing". So I'm at my desktop, I have to leave because I've lost track of time and I have to be in lectures, so I just want to push and not commit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Push changes to remote repo without commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582578/push-changes-to-remote-repo-without-commit)

Answer (score 1):

Yea, just push to a branch.

```
$ git status
  On branch working-branch
  /MyFile
  /AnotherFile

$ git add MyFile AnotherFile
$ git commit -m "current changes"
$ git push --set-upstream origin working-branch
```

Now you can check out that branch from another computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary commit and push it to a temporary branch.

On your other machine, you can fetch the temporary branch, check it out, then reset back to master to go back to your in-progress state.

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
git push
```

and your branch will be in remote. From somewhere you can do

```
git fetch
```

And your branch will be in your local now. So simply

```
git checkout your_branch
```

and continue your job

Answer (score 0):

If it's the commit message that's stopping you, why not commit a trivial message (empty string, the letter A, etc), then when you have time, do `git commit --amend -m "New commit message"` and write something more meaningful?

Comment: I tried amending a push commit. I will never never never ever do it again.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: @DaveWeber He will never never never ever do it again because you're telling him to **rewrite history!** That's one of the biggest no-no's in Git usage. It's fine if you never pushed your original commit yet, or you're the only person to ever use the repository. But if you collaborate with others, amending commits that you already pushed and force pushing the amends will create a very messy situation for everyone involved.

Answer (score 0):

if you work in dropbox folder you dont need to push any think or revert commit

then when you feel like push you can still push to remote

Comment: Why use Dropbox at all if you have Git?

Comment: @sircapsalot yes, I use GitHub.  I just don't understand why anyone would use Git with Dropbox.  I've seen SO threads on it but still don't buy the arguments for it.

Comment: @jcm no, I completely agree - dropbox is a ridiculous idea. I was just making sure you disambiguate Git and Github. `:)`

Comment: @jcm, sircapsalot: I can see the point. Push to github your versioned changes, keeping your branches in an always-good state. Don't clutter history with pointless Work In Progress commits ("Halfway through this big file; need to go home"). Use dropbox so you can continue editing from another machine. Not sure *I'd* use the workflow, but it makes *sense*.

Comment: @Chowlett explained work flow completely. If you work on project with many  developers you need to keep your commits accordiognly features.  If your work interrups you may not want make dirty commits.